# Tv show with invisible boy

Tags: story-identification, tv

I vaugely remember a TV show, it may or may not have been black and white but in it there was a school boy who could become invisible when he asjusted his school tie. He may have been a ghost, my memory is not great.

Comment: Is it this Goosebumps episode? http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0591349/

Comment: is it "The Invisible Boy" (1957) black and white film. The synopsis doesn't say how his invisibility worked. http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0050546/

Comment: @Richard: Sorry, I'm confused; shouldn't ATB be the judge?

Comment: @Richard: Ah, yes, well it's the best I could do with the limited info given ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like what you're looking for:

*[Nobody's House](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0286376/)* - TV Series 1976

Moreton played an orphan child Ghost called "Nobody" in this made for children Tyne Tees Television series that aired for seven, 25 minute episodes in 1976.

The plot revolved around a 1970s contemporary family, the Sinclairs, that move into an old Victorian house "Cornerstones", that was built in 1885. This house was built on the site of what was previously an old Victorian workhouse "Burnsey Workhouse" in which a young orphan boy had died of the plague many years before while working in the workhouse. The boy had not "crossed over", and remained as a ghost in the house and over the years he continued to haunt the old Victorian house.

The house had been empty for years until the Sinclair's view the property. Having been made aware of a ghost occupying the property by the estate agent, Mr Jacobs, they decide to buy the property after their offer to buy it at half the asking price was accepted.

Strange things begin to happen when the family move into the house. The two Sinclair children first meet the ghost in Gilly's upstairs bedroom, after the ghost manifests himself to them and warns them that there is a fire in the cellar. Later the children meet the ghost and they ask him his name. The child ghost could not remember his name, so the children who now decide to befriend him (Moreton) call him Nobody, thus, Nobody's house.

No one except the two children could see the ghost "Nobody". The ghost wore grey Victorian workhouse or street urchin clothes and when he wanted to "ghost" in or out of sight he would tug on his neck-scarf.

From Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kevin_Moreton
Youtube:

Comment: You sir are amazing

Comment: No problem. Happy to help.